# Problem with implementation own version of KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>

Tags: c#

In VS 2017 we have an implementation of KeyValuePair like

```
    namespace System.Collections.Generic
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Defines a key/value pair that can be set or retrieved.
        //
        // Type parameters:
        //   TKey:
        //     The type of the key.
        //
        //   TValue:
        //     The type of the value.
        public struct KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>
        {
            //
            // Summary:
            //     Initializes a new instance of the System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2 structure
            //     with the specified key and value.
            //
            // Parameters:
            //   key:
            //     The object defined in each key/value pair.
            //
            //   value:
            //     The definition associated with key.
            public KeyValuePair(TKey key, TValue value);

            //
            // Summary:
            //     Gets the key in the key/value pair.
            //
            // Returns:
            //     A TKey that is the key of the System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2.
            public TKey Key { get; }
            //
            // Summary:
            //     Gets the value in the key/value pair.
            //
            // Returns:
            //     A TValue that is the value of the System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2.
            public TValue Value { get; }

            //
            // Summary:
            //     Returns a string representation of the System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2,
            //     using the string representations of the key and value.
            //
            // Returns:
            //     A string representation of the System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2, which
            //     includes the string representations of the key and value.
            public override string ToString();
        }
    }
```

I would like to implement my own KeyValuePair with diffrent name.
My code

```
    namespace IEnumerableTest1
    {
        public struct ParameterNameValuePair<TParameterName, TValue>
        {
            public ParameterNameValuePair(TParameterName parameterName, TValue value);
            public TParameterName ParameterName { get; }
            public TValue Value { get; }
            public override string ToString();
        }
    }
```

Now, I have error in code:

> Error CS0501  'ParameterNameValuePair.ParameterNameValuePair(TParameterName, TValue)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial   IEnumerableTest1
>
> Error CS0501  'ParameterNameValuePair.ToString()' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial   IEnumerableTest1

How to solve above problems?

Comment: You need to implement the constructor `ParameterNameValuePair` and even the `ToString` function.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is pretty clear: your constructor and `ToString()` are missing bodies. The code you've shown from `KeyValuePair<,>` is only a kind of contract, not the real code. The real code can be found in the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/keyvaluepair.cs,8585965bb176a426)

You can do it like that:

```
 public struct ParameterNameValuePair<TParameterName, TValue>
 {
     // implement constructor to assign values
     public ParameterNameValuePair(TParameterName parameterName, TValue value)
     {
         ParameterName = parameterName;
         Value = value;
     }

     public TParameterName ParameterName { get; }
     public TValue Value { get; }

     // implement ToString() to return a meaningful string representation
     public override string ToString() => $"[{Key}]: {Value}";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Or straight from [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/keyvaluepair.cs)

```
[Serializable]
public struct KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> {
    private TKey key;
    private TValue value;

    public KeyValuePair(TKey key, TValue value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public TKey Key {
        get { return key; }
    }

    public TValue Value {
        get { return value; }
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        StringBuilder s = StringBuilderCache.Acquire();
        s.Append('[');
        if( Key != null) {
            s.Append(Key.ToString());
        }
        s.Append(", ");
        if( Value != null) {
           s.Append(Value.ToString());
        }
        s.Append(']');
        return StringBuilderCache.GetStringAndRelease(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because your struct constructor and ToString method don't have the body. Add them and then it should compile.

Example:

```
public ParameterNameValuePair(TParameterName parameterName, TValue value)
{
  ParameterName = parameterName;
  Value = value;
}

public override string ToString()
{
  return $"{ParameterName.ToString()} {Value.ToString()}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the methods.

The code that VS shows when you go to definition for code in an assembly is generated in a form that is not itself valid C#: if has the function declarations but no implementation. This is very useful when you want to know the available members of a type, but not how one writes code.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor needs  implementation:

```
public struct ParameterNameValuePair<TParameterName, TValue>
{
    public ParameterNameValuePair(TParameterName parameterName, TValue value)
    {
        ParameterName = parameterName;
        Value = value;
    }
    public TParameterName ParameterName { get; private set; }
    public TValue Value { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to missing body of your functions i.e. constructor and overloaded ToString()
Implement your constructor. Modify your properties with get and **set**

something like

```
public struct ParameterNameValuePair<TParameterName, TValue>
        {
            private TParameterName  key;
            private TValue value;
            public ParameterNameValuePair(TParameterName parameterName, TValue value)
            {
                 this.key = parameterName;
                 this.value= value;
            }

            public TParameterName ParameterName { get;}
            public TValue Value { get;}
            public override string ToString()
            {
                 return $"Key: {ParameterName.ToString()}, Value:{Value.ToString()}";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your properties won't work as expected, they don`t access the backing field.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio only displays the Contract of a datatype, if it cannot access the sources. You can find the actual implementation of `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/keyvaluepair.cs,8585965bb176a426).

In your concrete example you have to provide an implementation for each method like this:

```
public struct ParameterNameValuePair<TParameterName, TValue>
{
    public ParameterNameValuePair(TParameterName parameterName, TValue value)
    {
        ParameterName = parameterName;
        Value = value;
    }

    public TParameterName ParameterName { get; }
    public TValue Value { get; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Parameter={ParameterName}, Value={Value}";
    }
}
```