# Implement IEnumrable<T> for Dictionary with own KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>

Tags: c#, ienumerable, ienumerator

Following my question 
[Problem with implementation own version of KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52511587/problem-with-implementation-own-version-of-keyvaluepairtkey-tvalue/52511730#52511730)
now I wont to change the class code

```
   public class VectorType<TKey, TValue> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
    {
        string variableName;
        Dictionary<TKey, TValue> paramteresList;

        public VectorType(string variableName)
        {
            this.variableName = variableName;
            paramteresList = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
        }

        public void Add(TKey parameterName, TValue parametereValue)
        {
            paramteresList.Add(parameterName, parametereValue);
        }

        public int NumberOfParameters
        {
            get { return paramteresList.Count; }
        }

        public string VariableName
        {
            get { return variableName; }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IEnumerable)paramteresList).GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return paramteresList.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

to use my own implementation of KeyValuePair as

```
public struct ParameterNameKeyValuePair<TParameterNameKey, TValue>
{
    private TParameterNameKey key;
    private TValue value;

    public ParameterNameKeyValuePair(TParameterNameKey key, TValue value)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public TParameterNameKey Key
    {
        get { return key; }
    }

    public TValue Value
    {
        get { return value; }
    }
}
```

If I change KeyValuePair to ParameterNameKeyValuePair I have

```
    public class VectorType<TParameterNameKey, TValue> : IEnumerable<ParameterNameKeyValuePair<TParameterNameKey, TValue>>
    {
        string variableName;
        Dictionary<TParameterNameKey, TValue> paramteresList;

        public VectorType(string variableName)
        {
            this.variableName = variableName;
            paramteresList = new Dictionary<TParameterNameKey, TValue>();
        }

        public void Add(TParameterNameKey parameterName, TValue parametereValue)
        {
            paramteresList.Add(parameterName, parametereValue);
        }

        public int NumberOfParameters
        {
            get { return paramteresList.Count; }
        }

        public string VariableName
        {
            get { return variableName; }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IEnumerable)paramteresList).GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator<ParameterNameKeyValuePair<TParameterNameKey, TValue>> IEnumerable<ParameterNameKeyValuePair<TParameterNameKey, TValue>>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return paramteresList.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

and I have error at compile time: Cannot implicitly convert type 
'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.Enumerator' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator>'
in line

```
        IEnumerator<ParameterNameKeyValuePair<TParameterNameKey, TValue>> IEnumerable<ParameterNameKeyValuePair<TParameterNameKey, TValue>>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return paramteresList.GetEnumerator();
        }
```

I only change KeyValuePair to ParameterNameKeyValuePair. Whay I have this error ? And second question, It is safe to implement owne KeyValuePair like in my case ParameterNameKeyValuePair?

Comment: `Dictionary` has nothing to do with what you are trying to do here. You are trying to implement a completely different interface. You can't just cast the `IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` returned by `Dictionary.GetEnumerator` to your own. `ParameterNameKeyValuePair` would have to inherit from `KeyValuePair` at least, but structs don't support inheritance. You'll have to create a *new* struct* for each one returned by that enumerator. *Why* are you creating your own pair struct anyway?

Comment: What is the reason for your own type? Why not just use `KeyValuePair`?

Comment: If you *must* do this, you will have to create instances of your own key value pair type for each element of the original dictionary. Something like `return parameteresList.Select(kvp => new ParameterNameKeyValuePair(kvp.Key, kvp.Value));`

Comment: I use own pair struct "ParameterNameKeyValuePair" because the name of this pair give more information about the key in Dictionary and is street connected to a problem that I wont to solve. I also curious about how to solve this problem.

Comment: Well... change `Dictionary<TParameterNameKey, TValue>` to `List<ParameterNameKeyValuePair<TParameterNameKey, TValue>>`... But this sounds very much like re-inventing the wheel...

Comment: I need Dictionary, so I will use KeyValuePair.

Comment: Changing to a custom implementation from BCL only in order to have a different class name? That seems _very_ odd to me. Maybe this is some kind of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: ... you *could* also re-implement `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` to use `ParameterNameKeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`...

Comment: I use ParameterNameKeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> with List<>. Now, In my problem, I can not use Dictionary because I have the same key in date. Let's say that I have a "special problem" to solve :). Of course, changing to a custom implementation it is not good programming practices. I was curious and now I know more about programming in C# :)